# Kadena Chainweaver Login question & VirtualBox Chainweaver size problem

Tags: blockchain, contract

Question 1:
Every time I load https://chainweaver.kadena.network my password doesn't work and I have to restore the wallet from the recovery phrase. Any idea why?

Question2:
Because of this i tried using the VM Chainweaver instead of their website link found here: https://chainweaver-builds.s3.amazonaws.com/2.2/kadena-chainweaver-vm-2.2.0.1.ova

It's a Developer-friendly wallet and smart contract development environment for Kadena for VirtualBox found here: https://docs.kadena.io/manage-your-kda/wallets#chainweaver

But it doesn't display correctly in the VM I tried adding Guest Additions and I run them for linux like this:
"sudo /run/media/chainweaver/VBox_GAs_6.1.30/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run" but I get this error:

Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 6.1.30 Guest Additions for Linux........
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Unable to determine correct library path.
./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run: line 402: /bin/rm: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1: I was using incognito mode and Chainweaver didn't have my local storage for me to login with just the password and I had to put my 12 word phrase everytime to restore the wallet. Web Chainweaver is not just a website. It's an independent application which runs into the browser. It only uses local storage of your browser. It's not like Metamask that can storage your account using incognito mode because it's not a browser extension, it's a different concept and when you close the website using incognito mode you will need your seed phrase next time to login to your wallet. So just stop using incognito mode with Web Chainweaver or just use the VM (Answer Question 2).

Question 2: That VM found in https://chainweaver-builds.s3.amazonaws.com/2.2/kadena-chainweaver-vm-2.2.0.1.ova isn't using Linux. Its NixOS so the VirtualBox Guest Addition will not work running linux To fix the size problem on VirualBox click on View -> Full Screen Mode. See image below. [click on View -> Full Screen Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37Fvj.png)